# Retry a selected file upload in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, web, upload

Scenario: user is able to upload multiple files by drag & drop or file dialog, the uploading and tracking works fine, but now the user wants a retry function.

situation:

1. user tries to upload form
2. form gets rejected for lack of content
3. user fixes form while still in web-session
4. user saves form that is on local computer
5. user clicks retry

at step 5 I am having trouble understanding how i can retrieve that changed file, i have a file object that contains the original file info, ive tried creating a new instance of a file object using the file name, but im beginning to think theres not a way to accomplish this because i would be programatically accessing the users computer to update the file.

any thoughts or help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

> would be programatically accessing the users computer to update the
>   file.

You can't do this programatically . File input is readonly one way for security issue. You can only reach with clicking it